# SQL WHERE clause filter from more than one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, where-clause

I have a table:

```
RowID      QuestionNum   Survey
--------------------------------
ABC          1             1
DEF          2             1
ASD          3             1
RDS          4             1
TGH          5             1
YHG          1             2
TGF          2             2
UHJ          3             2
UJH          4             2
IJK          5             2
UJH          6             2
```

RowID is string, QuestionNum and Survey are INT.

All I want to do is exclude:

- QuestionNum 5 and Survey 1
- QuestionNum 6 and Survey 2

This is my SQL:

```
SELECT RowID, QuestionNum, SurveyType
FROM dbo.tblTest
WHERE (SurveyType <> 1) 
  AND (QuestionNum <> 5) 
   OR (SurveyType <> 2) AND (QuestionNum <> 6)
```

But it returns all rows - what am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> All I want to do is exclude QuestionNum 1 and Survey 1 AND QuestionNum 6 and Survey 2

You could phrase this condition as :

```
WHERE NOT (
    (SurveyType = 1 AND QuestionNum = 5) 
    OR (SurveyType = 2 AND QuestionNum = 6)
)
```

Answer (score 3):

If the list of pairs is too big you can use a set based approach:

```sql
SELECT RowID, QuestionNum, Survey
FROM t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM (VALUES
        (1, 1),
        (6, 2)
        -- add moar pairs
    ) AS e(QuestionNum, Survey)
    WHERE t.QuestionNum = e.QuestionNum AND t.Survey = e.Survey
)
```

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6fc850a4f1f8e571161b3f1143bcc054)

Answer (score 2):

I always have trouble interpreting `NOT(...)` conditions on SQL, so I go the positive way:

```
SELECT
    RowID, 
    QuestionNum, 
    SurveyType
FROM
    dbo.tblTest
WHERE
    (
        QuestionNum <> 1 OR                     -- Either question number isn't 1
        (QuestionNum = 1 AND SurveyType <> 1)   -- ... or if it is 1, then survey type mustn't be 1
    ) 
    AND
    (
        QuestionNum <> 6 OR                     -- Either question number isn't 6
        (QuestionNum = 6 AND SurveyType <> 2)   -- ... or if it is 6, then survey type musn't be 2
    )
```

Will have to watch against `NULL` values, if they are possible on your columns. Read Salman's solution if you have a bunch of rows to exclude.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of operator precedence while translating your requirement into Query, 
exclude:

```
QuestionNum 1 and Survey 1
QuestionNum 6 and Survey 2
```

: following should work fine in your case :

```
SELECT RowID, QuestionNum, SurveyType
FROM dbo.tblTest
WHERE (SurveyType <> 1 AND QuestionNum <> 1) 
   OR (SurveyType <> 2 AND QuestionNum <> 6)
```